# How to set visual states for custom buttons

Tags: c#, templates, button, uwp

I have a UWP app which uses some custom round buttons that i've found sample code for online. It uses a filled eclipse and looks great. The only problem is I can't figure out how to make the button transparant when it is disabled.

I have tried entering code into the visual state x:Name Disabled tag. But I'm not sure I fully understand the sample code I found online! The fill appears to have nothing to do with the state.

So.... my question is. How do I keep the buttons looking exactly like they do now (round with gradient fill). But also enable some effect for when the button is disabled. For example changing the color, or changing the transparancy? I've been trying to figure this out for days now and am going round in circles!

Thank you :)

```
<Page.Resources>
<Style x:Key="OffSiteButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="OrangeRed"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Inner" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Outer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Ellipse Margin="4" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" x:Name="Outer"/>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse Margin="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" x:Name="Inner"/>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: FYI Duplicating tags in your question title doesn't provide any benefit, and it goes against the tagging guidelines.

Comment: @John ok sorry about that. i was just trying to make it easy for people to see it applies to uwp and c#. if i was reading the titles on the forum i don't check the tags.

Comment: Fortunately this isn't a forum - it's a targetted Q/A site. People follow tags they are interested in. Don't worry - people will find your questione easily :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you assign your `Ellipse` element an `x:Name`, you could for example animate its `Fill` property using a `Storyboard` and an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`. You could also animate the `Opacity` property of the `Button` itself using a `DoubleAnimation`:

```
<Style x:Key="OffSiteButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Orange"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="OrangeRed"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Silver"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.1" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Inner" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Outer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="OuterEllipse" Margin="4" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" x:Name="Outer"/>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="InnerEllipse" Margin="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" x:Name="Inner"/>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: wow! you are a genius! Thank you :)
Only thing I am having trouble with is the double animation to set the transparency. it says failed to add child at index 1. but i am still playing around with that anyway

Comment: The code above works with the exception of the transparency. I would really like to get the button to be transparent. I will double check i didn't make a mistake copying the code above. but i'm having problems with the double animation.